# Java - JSoup Post aspx

Tags: java, android, jsoup

get info from form

http://www.qiyas.org/QiyasResult/Pages/ResultsPage.aspx

I tried the following with no success...

```
doc = Jsoup
                    .connect(
                            "http://www.qiyas.org/QiyasResult/Pages/ResultsPage.aspx")

                    .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TestResultsAr$SearchBy",
                            "RadioButtonByNationalNumber")
                    .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TestResultsAr$TextBoxNumber",
                            "1065333658")
                    .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TestResultsAr$ButtonSearch",
                            "بحث")
                            .data("action", "ResultsPage.aspx")
                    // and other hidden fields which are being passed in
                    // post
                    // request.
                    .userAgent(
                            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0")
                    .post();
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It works fine on my pc. `System.out.println(doc);` Doesn't this print anything?

Comment: yes but don't show me my degree in test you can test this number 1065333658 in fields and show result in website